# JS Extract Exponent from String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS String containing "x²".

Problem: How do I extract the "2" out of the string in JavaScript to then convert it to a number?
Is there any way i can remove the "^" that should be before the exponent?
I already tried

```
string.replace("\^","");"
```

Or can I remove the format of the string?

I also tried

```
parseInt(string.substr(2));
```

Comment: *"Is there any way i can remove the "^" that should be before the exponent?"* Huh? There isn't one there, how could you remove it?

Comment: You could probably do better then this to explain what you really want. You have a string, does it look like `x²` or does it look like a random value, a `^` character and an exponent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you have `"x²"` and want to turn it into `"x^2"`, it's a trivial replacement:

```
str = str.replace(/²/g, "^2");
```

If you want to handle both of those (there's also a `³`), you could either do a chained replace:

```
str = str.replace(/²/g, "^2").replace(/³/g, "^3");
```

...or use a callback:

```
str = str.replace(/[²³]/g, function(m) {
    return "^" + String.fromCharCode(m.charCodeAt(0) - 128);
});
```

-128 is the char code difference between `²` (char code 178) and `2` (char code 50), with `³` (179) and 3 (51) just after them.